# Difference between Multi Dimension Array and Associative Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I Know what are arrays and how they work but having a problem with multi dimension array using foreach

here is code :

```
foreach($my_formats_array as $format) {
parse_str($format);
$avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
$avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
$avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
$i++; }
```

`$i is iterator = 0` , loop is running , `i` incremented as the loop run, but is this happening

`$avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;` ?

Could Someone Please explain that with reference link so i can learn about this logic

Where :

```
$avail_formats[] = '';
$i = 0;
$ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
$expire = time();
```

Thanks

Comment: can you var_dump($format) before parse_str, and let us knwo what you get

Comment: Let's take [this example](http://pastebin.com/CReSD9up). It will output [this](http://pastebin.com/39Pjm7ru). What is that you don't understand?

Comment: @machineaddict what is that bar sir?

Comment: @machineaddict in example its making more sense to me unless the "bar"?

Comment: @machineaddict what does second parameter($exit = FALSE) in function (print_a) do? in the example you just showed?

Comment: `print_a` is just a function to pretty print the array in my browser without the need of seeing the page source. just use `print_r` instead of `print_a`. and about that parameter, if you are setting it true, it will stop the execution of the following code.

Comment: @HassanNaseer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples